# Question regarding the proof: If $n\in N^+$ and $A_i $, $1\leq i\leq n$ are countable sets then $A_1\times A_2\times\cdots\times A_n$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I understand the majority of the above proof and I also appreciate that:
 $(A_1\times  A_2\times \cdots\times A_n) \times A_{n+1}$ is not the same as saying $A_1\times  A_2\times \cdots\times A_n \times A_{n+1}$

and so in order to prove that $A_1 \times A_2\times\cdots \times A_n \times A_{n+1}$ is countable we need to prove that that there exists a bijection between $A_1 \times A_2\times\cdots \times A_n \times A_{n+1}$
and  $(A_1 \times A_2\times\cdots \times A_n) \times A_{n+1}$ (which we know to be countable from the assumption in the proof) to imply that they have the same cardinality which is $\aleph_0$ and hence is countable.

However the step confusing me is the construction of this bijection at line (36). I know a bijection is a one to one map (both a subjection and injection) but I am unsure how we can be so sure that this function is indeed a bijection.

Comment: Every $(n+1)$-tuple in $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_{n+1}$ gives you an element in $(A_1 \times \cdots \times A_{n}) \times A_{n+1}$ just by packing the first $n$ entries into their own tuple and pairing it with the $(n+1)$th. The reverse of this process is the function $f$. (Honestly, it's pointless pedantry to treat set products as non-associative like this.)

Comment: It's not pointless in an intro class, @ConnorHarris. It is important to treat definitions with care in intro classes.

Answer (score 0):

You assumed you had a bijection between $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)$ and the naturals.  You can therefore have a function $g$ that will pack $n$ naturals into one, like the pairing function you just showed for two naturals.  You use $g$ to pack the first $n$ elements of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n,a_{n+1})$ into one, use the pairing function to pack the two elements into one, and that is your function $f$.  How was $g$ defined?  The same way starting from $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The bijectivity of the function 
$$f:(A_1\times A_2\times.....\times A_n)\times A_{n+1}\to A_1\times A_2.....\times A_n\times A_{n+1}$$
immediately follows from the fact that ordered pairs are unique. Lets give  a non-rigorous proof that $f$ is injective. For ease of notation, I use $f:A\to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are the same as written above.

Suppose there exists $x=(a_1,a_2,a_3.....,,a_n,a_{n+1})$ in $B$ such that both $((b_1,b_2,b_3...,b_n),b_{n+1})$ and $((c_1,c_2,c_3...,c_n),c_{n+1})$ in $A$ map to $x$. By the definition of $f$, we see immediately that $$b_{n+1}=c_{n+1}$$and that $$(b_1,b_2.....,b_n)=(c_1,c_2,.....,c_n)$$
which shows that $f$ is injective.

Now, choose any $y=(a_1,a_2,a_3....,a_n,a_{n+1})\in B$. So, choosing $$x=((a_1,a_2,....,a_n),a_{n+1})$$ so that $x\in A$
shows that $f(x)=y$, so that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding line (36).

Def'n: $[[n]]=\{j\in \mathbb N:j\leq n\}$ for $n \in \mathbb N.$

Define $\prod_{i\in [[n]]}A_i$ to be the set of functions $g:[[n]]\to \cup_{i\in [[n]]}A_i$ that satisfy $g(i)\in A_i$ for each $i\in [[n]].$

For brevity let $C=\prod_{i\in [[n+1]]}A_i.$

Let  $B_1=\prod_{i\in [[n]]}A_i$ and $B_2=A_{n+1}.$ Define $f:(B_1\times B_2)\to C$ by  $f(b)=b(1)\cup \{(n+1,b(2)\}$.

If $f(b)=f(b')$ then $$\{(i, b(1)(i)):i\in [[n]]\}\cup \{(n+1,b(2)\}=\{(i,b'(1)(i)):i\in [[n]]\}\cup \{(n+1, b'(2)\},$$ which implies that $\forall i\in [[n]]\;(b(1)(i)=b'(1)(i)\}$ and $b(2)=b'(2),$ which implies $b(1)=b'(1)$ and $b(2)=b'(2).$

That is, $f(b)=f(b')\implies b=b'.$

So $f$ is injective.

For $c\in C,$ take $b=\{(1, c|_{[[n]]}), (2, c(n+1)\}$ where $c|_{[[n]]}=\{(j,c(j):j\in [[n]]\}.$ Then $b\in B_1\times B_2$ and $f(b)=c.$

So $f$ is surjective.